# QuillJS - How to open the toolbar programmatically

Tags: javascript, quill

I am currently running QuillJS v2.0.0-dev.4. According to the [docs](https://quilljs.com/docs/modules/keyboard/), I should be able to do something along these lines

```
const quill = new Quill($target[0]);

function openToolbar(range, context){
   //what code goes here?
}

quill.keyboard.addBinding({ key:'/' }, openToolbar);
```

In other words, when a user presses the `/` (forward slash) key on the keyboard, I need to open the QuillJS toolbar. Right now the only way to open that toolbar is by selecting something inside the editor. Screenshot attached.

[image]

What is the code that needs to go into the `openToolbar` function?